# how to clean up global and local variables for a single python script

Tags: python, ide

I have a single Python script with over 3000 lines and mixed local and global variables. I am trying to clean it up and split it into modules, the main difficulty I encounter is the pollution of local and global variables. I wonder if there is any tool that can help me track where those variables are used?

Answer (score 1):

Some IDEs (like [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-usages-in-project.html)) are good at finding usages of selected variable.

Other way, you can just apply full-text search. But this approach can give many false "usages".

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a more automatic tool. My current emacs setup can do usage searching, as well. I guess it may not exist.